# Why does this Oracle PLSQL function need to be recompiled when a table is updated?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have written this function for an Oracle db for a class project:

```
create or replace Function loginUser ( name_in IN varchar2, pass_in IN varchar2 )
Return Number
IS
   cursor c1 is
   SELECT u_id
     FROM userinfo
     WHERE username = name_in AND pass = pass_in AND lockedout='N';

  user_id_return  number;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN 

   open c1;
   fetch c1 into user_id_return;

   if c1%notfound then
    user_id_return := 0;
    INSERT INTO LoginAttempt(username, whenattempted, attempt_status) VALUES (name_in, SYSDATE, 'N');
    commit;
   ELSE
    INSERT INTO LoginAttempt(username, whenattempted, attempt_status) VALUES (name_in, SYSDATE, 'Y');
    commit;
   END IF;

   close c1;

Return user_id_return;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

It works great, I get an insert into a table called `LoginAttempt` when you call

```
SELECT loginUser('name','pass') FROM DUAL;
```

The issue, however, is that new records and updates to userinfo are not reflected in the SELECT statement at the top of the function.

I have to recompile the function each time I update the userinfo table.

Why is this? Is this how functions with SELECT statements work? Is the table that is being SELECTED from compiled when the function is compiled?

Is this related to the PRAGME AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION bit?

The schema for the table can be found on github (https://github.com/tmsimont/cs3810schema/blob/master/export.sql)

Comment: Can you explain how you insert new records into the userinfo table? Maybe you are doing it from a different session and aren't committing the inserts?

Comment: that is possible. i'm just using sqldeveloper. I'm not too familiar with the software. I type in the command into a window and hit F5... When I call INSERT INTO userinfo ... I hit F5.. When I later come back and do SELECT * FROM userinfo, I do see my changes... I'll have to do some more testing to see what's up with SQLDeveloper and what F5 does. Thanks for the lead

Comment: OK sorry for the lame comment.. All I know about F5 is that is calls "Run script" -- I'm just writing "INSERT INTO userinfo (username, pass) VALUES ('Trevor,'TEST')" -- I don't think that the "RUN SCRIPT" in SQLDeveloper would involve commiting the query, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function executes its DML in an autonomous transaction (i.e. a separate session to the calling one), it cannot see data that has not been committed by the calling session. Until your code commits, the changes it makes are not visible to any other session, including the one used by your function.

This has nothing to do with needing to compile the function. The reason compilation caused it to suddenly see the data is because DDL always issues a commit, thus having the side effect of committing the data you had inserted.

Comment: Yes I thought that F5 in SQL Developer was committing changes, but it's not. You have to hit F11. This is a little different from Microsoft SQL Server